# Dart: pass named arguments to function through a variable

Tags: function, dart

I'm trying to figure out how do I pass a variable with arguments to a function with named parameters. This is what I have tried so far:

```
  fn({String a, String b, String c}) {
    return '$a $b $c';
  }

  var args = {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 'c': 'baz'};

  print(fn(args)); // Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

  print(Function.apply(fn, null, args)); // The argument type 'Map<String, String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<Symbol, dynamic>'
```

It looks like the latter approach is the way to go, but I'm not sure about what's a symbol in this case.  Can it be done like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `Map<Symbol, String>` as third argument but you have a `Map<String, String>` to convert it you can use the `.map` method and create an instance of the `Symbol` class like this:

```
  print(Function.apply(fn, null, args.map((key, value) => MapEntry(Symbol(key), value))));
}
```

or you can create right away a `Map<Symbol, String>`:

```
var args = {#a: 'foo', ...};
```